# iOS 10 : how accurate is CLVisit in CoreLocation

Tags: core-location

I'm looking to use CLVisit in CoreLocation (iOS 10) to get information about where my app users have visited and for how long, but couldn't find much information about the current accuracy.

The documentation in iOS 8 mentioned that it can't distinguish a quick, real stop at a store vs. long stop at a traffic light... (so potentially I might be missing data about actual places visited) Has this improved since then?